# sum of elements multiplied by 3 in haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to create a function which takes an n elements long list and returns sum of all elements multiplied by 3. The way I do it is here:

```
times3::Int->Integer
times3 x = sum [map (3*) [1..x]]
```

This code however results in the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Integer' with actual type `[Int]'
```

Do you have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: You can simplify this to `times3 x = div (3*x*(x+1)) 2`

Answer (score 3):

`[map (3*) [1..x]]` is a list of length *one*, since `[ some expression here ]` is always a singleton list. In your code it's the list-of-lists `[[3,6,...,3*x]]` of type `[[Int]]` as the compiler reported.

Your type signature claims the result is `Integer`, and to obtain that, we would need to start with list of type `[Integer]`. The compiler checks the type equality `[[Int]] ~ [Integer]` and complains that `[Int]` is not `Integer`, hence the type error.

Instead, `(map (3*) [1..x])` is a list of length `x`, namely `[3,6,...,3*x]`, which is of type `[Int]`. This is the list I think you intended to use.

Since this list is not a `[Integer]`, you either have to perform a conversion using `fromIntegral` or, more simply, to change your type signature in the function.

Another alternative would be to make the argument `x` an `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

[@chi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65075049/67579) explains what the problem is with the current implementation. The only thing I want to add is that the sum of *3, 6, 9, …, *3×n*; can be determined without enumerating over a list. Indeed the sum:

```
 n              n
---            ---
\              \
/   3 i  =  3  /    i
---            ---
i=1            i=1
```

the sum if 1, 2, …, n can be calculated with *n×(n+1)/2*, so we can calculate the sum with:

```
times3 :: Int -> Integer
times3 n = 3 * div (n * (ni+1)) 2
    where ni = fromIntegral n
```

or without converting an `Int` to `Integer` and for any `Integral` type:

```
times3 :: Integral i => i -> i
times3 n = 3 * div (n * (n+1)) 2
```